# Why do I have blank friends in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When looking at my friends list in Diablo 3, I noticed that there are several accounts listed that have no name.  All my friends are accounted for, so I don't think that's the cause.

My best guess at the moment is that they are the friends that I added during the beta, because I had to re-add them when the game released.  If this **is** the cause for the phantom friends, how do I delete them?

[image]

Comment: Note that the last 3 friends displayed are intentionally obscured, but the top three (freehand circled) are unedited.

Comment: I can barely make out a few names in the background of the minimap - are that their (misplaced) names?

Comment: @WielandH. Those are actually from the mumble overlay.  The people up there are the people I was in my mumble server with.  That's actually a really good point of clarification, though, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to remove them like any other friend.  Otherwise you might have to report the bug to Blizzard using the in-game tools.

Comment: I also played during the beta, and I have the same problem. I agree that its more likely the friends you added during the beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has now been fixed, and my friends list is now free of fake friends.

Answer (score 0):

This is a software bug.  It's likely that Blizzard is aware that it's happening, and at some point, they'll fix it, and it will stop happening.

Comment: Of course it is a bug, but what workarounds exist? is there a official statement on this?

Comment: I don't mean to be mean, but there is a workaround - ignore the blank entries. http://us.battle.net/support/en/blog/5367451 lists known issues, but this one was probably omitted because it's not a very important bug.